# How to use erc20 token in integer, not decimal

Tags: web3js, erc-20

I want to use number as normal integer, not in decimal.

For example, when I use uniswap function `IUniswapV2Router02Instance.methods.swapETHForExactTokens(1, , , ).send()` in my project, an argument integer (1) is recognized as decimal (0.000000000000000001) .

This is the transaction on etherscan.
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0x14d16174a7b12c1a77356b60b1fca7385c7cad583991d70b8a4423faf6198e43

Does anyone know why this problem happens and how to solve, please?

Comment: Yes, 1 = 1 wei. You need to use "1" followed by zeros, according to the number of decimals configured in your ERC20 token (which is 18 in most cases).

Comment: This number might be larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, so pass it as a string just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Thank you! How can I pass string to uint256 ?

Comment: web3.js takes care of that.

Comment: I got it !! I could do that ! By the way, is it better to use Bignumber in mu case?

Comment: You can use `Web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals)` I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wallets and other Dapp interfaces different tokens and assets are displayed as having decimals. Since the EVM doesn't really support normal decimal datatypes such as floats for example what most **ERC20** tokens do is they use integers and instead define a number of decimals (usually 18).

So when you receive `1 BAT` for example the smart contract will really register it as you having `1 * 10^18 BAT` just that the wallet displays it as 1 since the BAT smart contract defines its decimals as being 18. The same goes for Ether.

With Ether the base unit even has a name: wei, which is equivalent to `1 * 10^-18 ETH` or `0.000000000000000001 ETH`. So on a low level when you send tokens or ETH using code it treats the value as if it were in the base unit, in the case of ETH wei so when you send 1 unit of ether you are really sending 1 wei. Now 1 wei displayed in your wallet appears as a tiny decimal fraction. Hope that cleared things up!